# Scheduled Task in Bada OS

Tags: bada

Is there any hint whether Bada OS supported scheduled task ?

E.g. App A set a timer or schedule, then App A is suspended or closed. When the timer is expired, the application would be called and proceed.

Possible ? or any alternative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.

It seems that the only workaround is to write a Widget with HTML, then use setTimeout to trigger period functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in bada.

There can be only one bada application running at a time. If you start another one, the first one is pretty much killed (it's visible in task manager, but if you click on it - it just starts like you ran it from the menu).

So there's no way to run an app as a typical service in background.

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature is not available until SDK 1.1. There is a upcoming conditiona launch plan for near future.